# How to create tree view hierarchy in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

I have a array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [child_name] => "Emma"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Brown"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [id] => 2
            [child_name] => "John"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Brown"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [child_name] => "Joseph"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Thomas"
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [child_name] => "Pretty"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Thomas"
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [child_name] => "Raphel"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Brown"
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [child_name] => "Tommy"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Thomas"
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [child_name] => "Tim"
            [parent_name] => "Mr Thomas"
        )
)
```

From this array I want to generate a view like this :

[image]
The `parent_name` field becomes the MainCategory and the `child_name` becomes the subcategory. The names have checkboxes in front of them.

How do I achieve this? I don't have much experience in php. I code in node js but this task needs this to be done in php.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Here i use simple index() method and pass data to view file as an example.

You can use below code and test in your `codeigniter`.

Hope this will work for you.

> Welcome.php (Controller)

```
public function index()
{
    $array = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'child_name' => "Emma",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Brown",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'child_name' => "John",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Brown",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'child_name' => "Joseph",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Thomas",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 4,
            'child_name' => "Pretty",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Thomas",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 5,
            'child_name' => "Raphel",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Brown",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 6,
            'child_name' => "Tommy",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Thomas",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 7,
            'child_name' => "Tim",
            'parent_name' => "Mr Thomas",
        ],
        [
            'id' => 8,
            'child_name' => "William",
            'parent_name' => "",
        ],
    ];

    $resultArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value['parent_name'] != ''){
            $resultArray[$value['parent_name']][] = $value;
        }else{
            $resultArray[$value['child_name']] = [];
        }
    }
    $data = ['resultArray' => $resultArray];

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

> welcome_message.php (view)

```
<div>
    <form name='sample'>
        <?php 
        foreach ($resultArray as $parentKey => $parentValue) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$parentKey.'" value="'.$parentKey.'">'.$parentKey.'<br>';
            foreach ($parentValue as $childKey => $childValue) {
                echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="'.$childValue['child_name'].'" value="'.$childValue['child_name'].'">'.$childValue['child_name'].'<br>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: if one of the objects is  [
            'id' => 1,
            'child_name' => "Emma",
            'parent_name' => "",
        ]  i.e without the parent_name then in this case the child_name should become the parent name when displaying in the view. how to do it?

Comment: @node_man Please check my updated above code, here i take "id = 8" as your example and change my loop according to your requirement (please check output).

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

Loop your array, it will capture all values with same parent_name.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value['parent_name']][] = $value['child_name']; // loop your array
}
```

It should work.